# Bind to Service and execute some methods?

Tags: android, ipc, aidl

Ok, I understood, that when you bind to a remote `Service`, it won't bind until you return from the callback. I need to bind to a service and execute some method from it immediately. Is there any way? My code looks like:

```
try {
            Parser parser = FrameworkBridge.getFrameworkBridge(this).getParser();
            if (parser != null) {
                for (Article a : parser.getArticlesList("http://www.bt.dk/mecommobile/latest/news_article/%s/%s?output_type=xml", 1379, 20)) {
                    listAdapter.add(a);
                }
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service communication failure");
        } catch (FrameworkNotInstalledException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No framework installed. Install it!");
        }
```

Here `FrameworkBridge.getFrameworkBridge(this).getParser()` performs all service connection routine and returns remote interface. The problem is -- when I'm in the code above, the connection is not performed yet, therefore `parser` is `null`. How can I make it connect before exiting the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onServiceConnected(..) will tell you when the service is connected and the remote interface is established. Don't try to call any methods in the service until this is triggered.

Comment: Yeah, but until I get out of the callback, it is not connected. And if I wait in the loop for it to return true from `onServiceConnected`, it will be eternal loop: I'm not leaving the loop for it to bind, waiting till it binds.

Comment: Ok, I started an `AsyncTask` from `onServiceConnected`, that triggers `Handler` after it finishes, that updates UI with the information from `Service`. Thanks for idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
mContext.bindService( new Intent("name of the class"), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

the above method call on the copy of the context you store should automatically bind the service when you need it. I am not 100% sure, but this should help you out somewhat.

Comment: I am calling it on the copy of the context: I'm passing `this` to `FrameworkBridge` class, which then uses it to call `bindService` method.